# T-SQL Query issue incorrect syntax

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am not sure why the following SQL is not working. Please suggest. The query fails when I tried to SET to @year2.

```
declare @year char(2)
set @year = '14'
declare @year2 as char(2)

set @year2 = SELECT CAST(CAST('14' as int ) as int) + 1
select @year2
```

Comment: Casting usually works the first time, `CAST(CAST('14' as int ) as int)` is overkill. Is there any particular reason that you're trying to mix strings and integers? It doesn't tend to make life easier in the long run.

Answer (score 3):

> `@year2` is defined as `CHAR(2)` and you are attempting to SELECT an
>   `integer` value into it. You need to `CAST/CONVERT` it to `CHAR(2)`

```
set @year2 = (SELECT (CONVERT(CHAR(2), CAST('14' AS INT) + 1)))
```

Comment: Description part of this answer is the best thing, @nav100 see what he has write and why you were unable to cast  :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
DECLARE @year CHAR(2)
SET @year = '14'

DECLARE @year2 as CHAR(2)
SET @year2 = CAST(CAST('14' AS INT ) AS CHAR(2)) + 1
SELECT @year2
```

I removed `SELECT` and changed the last `AS INT` to `AS CHAR(2)`